# Setting expires for dokuwiki lib directory on nginx stops processing .php files

Tags: nginx, debian

I'm trying install DocuWiki script on nginx web server. Documentation says that I need to put following directive at nginx config file:

```
location ^~ /lib/ {
   expires 30d;
}
```

When I try to add this, nginx stops sending .php files from lib directory to php-fpm, and send it to me like octet-streams for download. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working configuration:

```
    location ~ ^/lib.*\.(gif|png|ico|jpg)$ {
                    expires 30d;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem stems from the fact that the expires 30d; line catching the php within the /lib directory.

My fix for it, is to only use that line for /lib/ entreis that do not contain .php

```
location ^~ /lib/^((?!php).)*${
  expires 30d;
}
```

should do the trick.

Still trying to get nice urls to work.